# Why is a function assigned to a variable executing when placed directly above a self-calling anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, function, scope

I am experiencing a strange result from running the following code:

```
var saySomethingElse, v;

// This function will not run when the nameless function runs, even if v and saySomethingElse are commented out.
function saySomething() {

  alert("something");

}

// When v is uncommented, this function will run when the nameless function below runs..
saySomethingElse = function() {

  alert("something else");

}

//v = "by uncommenting me, saySomethingElse will no longer be called.";

(function() {

  if (v) {

    alert("Now things are working normally.")

  }

  alert("This alert doesn't happen if v is commented out.");

})();
```

When this code runs, the anonymous function at the bottom calls `saySomethingElse` instead of its own content, but if `v` is uncommented, everything works as expected: `saySomethingElse` is not executed, and the anonymous function executes its own content. I expect this is probably normal behavior, but I am looking for an explanation. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Check out the fiddle: [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/LgLxda3L/6/)

Comment: It would do you good to learn how to use the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a semi-colon to the end of your anonymous function `saySomethingElse`

You should always properly end your anonymous functions with a semi-colon. Using a semi-colon to end a normal non-anonymous `function fooBar() {}` function is not necessary.

```js
var saySomethingElse, v;

// This function will not run when the nameless function runs, even if v and saySomethingElse are commented out.
function saySomething() {

  alert("something");

} // <-- Semi-colon not necessary.

// When v is uncommented, this function will run when the nameless function below runs..
saySomethingElse = function() {

  alert("something else");

};  // <-- Semi-colon recommended to prevent errors like you're getting.

//v = "by uncommenting me, saySomethingElse will no longer be called.";

(function() {

  if (v) {

    alert("Now things are working normally.")

  }

  alert("This alert doesn't happen if v is commented out.");

})();
```

The code now functions as you would expect now that the `saySomethingElse` has been properly terminated at the end.

This is because, in JavaScript, you are expected to use a semi-colon at the end of every statement. Anonymous function definitions are statements, just as any other variable definition.

Comment: Oooooooooh, that is infuriating. I just spent all that time for a missed semicolon. Thanks for the prompt response, though.